# How get multi-dimensional array from POST in Play Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

If I have a form like:

```
<input type="text" name="class[0][options][0]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="class[0][options][1]" value="2" />
<input type="text" name="class[0][options][2]" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="class[0][options][3]" value="4" />

<input type="text" name="class[1][options][0]" value="5" />
<input type="text" name="class[1][options][1]" value="6" />
<input type="text" name="class[1][options][2]" value="7" />
<input type="text" name="class[1][options][3]" value="8" />
```

How do I get this in Play?

I've looked at `Scope.params` but that seems to only provide a 1-dimensional array:

```
String[] val = params.getAll( "class" );
```

How do I get that data?